# Docker Exits Before Completing Golang Project Build

Tags: go, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Golang project using Docker but the process keeps exiting before it completes, here's a part of the output from the terminal:

```
github.com/kataras/go-template (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
The command '/bin/sh -c go get -v' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM golang:1.7

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/cram/rolldrove
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/cram/rolldrove

COPY . $GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/cram/rolldrove

RUN go get -v
RUN go build ./server.go

CMD ["./server"]
```

Help please, how do I fix this it? It was working before but then this started happening.

**edit**

Re-run with -x flag

```
github.com/kataras/go-template (download)
cd .
git clone https://github.com/kataras/go-template /go/src/github.com/kataras/go-template
cd /go/src/github.com/kataras/go-template
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd /go/src/github.com/kataras/go-template
git show-ref
cd /go/src/github.com/kataras/go-template
git submodule update --init --recursive
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
The command '/bin/sh -c go get -v -x' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The problem seems to be this line:

```
get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
```

Comment: Try adding a `-x` to go get to see exactly what command fails.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the result was the same... I'll edit the question with the output running -x flag

Comment: What else is in your docker build context? Are you adding _any_ other files besides `server.go`? Any git configuration? Copying and posting your Dockerfile into a new directory works, so you must have added something in that working directory.

Comment: I added some new Go files since last `docker build` but that's it, it doesn't seem to be completing the  `go get -v` step, it stops at `get "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert": verifying non-authoritative meta tag`. Maybe if I find out what `verifying non-authoritative meta tag` means in this case I could find a fix.

Comment: That line is perfectly normal, so I'm not sure what the error would be. Regardless, you're doing a `go get` on a package directory, and `go build` on a single file which is wrong. The `go get` command already built your package and installed the binary in `$GOPATH/bin`, so you don't need the `go build` line which isn't building everything correctly anyway.  If that doesn't fix the problem, create a new directory, start with what works, and add pieces until it breaks.

Comment: Removing the `go build` line didn't work, I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: FYI it's a common pattern to deploy a binary-only container (because it's much smaller.) You can have a `Dockerfile-build` responsible for configuring dependencies and build steps, and output the built binary to a volume mount point. Then execute a second Dockerfile that is basically `FROM alpine COPY myBin /myBin CMD myBin`

Comment: Thanks Plato, I figured it out after fighting with it the entire day... I'll post the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with one of the packages being imported.

I started removing and replacing the 3rd party packages being pulled in one at a time, doing a build after each. It eventually had a successful build after I removed a package from Github that I was using to generate `uuid`s.  I ended up using the `uuid` generator snippet I found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/4FkNSiUDMg).